# Example of two matrices such that $LM+ML=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

I am looking for some examples of $n\times n$ complex matrices $L$ and $M$ satisfying $LM=aML$, for some fixed $a\in \mathbb{C}$. In particular if we take $n>2$ and $a=-1$ then we can see that matrices of the form $AB=0=-BA$ gives the required result. But I need some non trivial examples. Please give some hints so that I can proceed.

> Should I look some different rings other than the matrix rings?

Comment: What about$$A=B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}?$$

Comment: It should be noted $\det(aML)=a^n\det(M)\det(L)=a^n\det(LM)$, so for most $a$-s you need a non-invertible matrix.

Comment: Also, $\operatorname{tr}(aML)=a\operatorname{tr}(LM)$ so for $a\ne 1$ we need $\operatorname{tr}(ML)=0$ too.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It will not work, product should be non zero

Comment: @MANI But is it possible? If we have $A, B\in\mathbb R^2$ with $AB+BA=O$, then $\det(AB) =\operatorname{tr}(AB) =0$, i.e. $AB$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ or to $O$. I don't believe that the first case would appear, but it's only a guess.

Comment: But you wrote $AB=0=BA$. Why do you say now that the “product should be non zero”?

Comment: @Jochen Sir, i have edited the question, can we look for marices of order greater than $2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am saying that matrices satisfying the relation $AB-0=BA$ will give the  required result, but can we have some examples of the form $AB=-BA$ with  the product $AB$ is non zero matrix, now I am not very precise for $n$, I have edited the question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos can i get this property $xy=-yx\neq 0$ in some other ring?

Comment: Either $|a|=1$, or $LM$ (and thus $ML$) is nilpotent. If $|a|=1$ then $a$ must be a root of unity (of order at most the dimension of $LM$ and $ML$), and the non-zero eigenvalues of $LM$ and $ML$ are also roots of unity. This is not difficult to prove from the fact that the non-zero eigenvalues of $ML$ and $LM$ must coincide, combined with $LM=aML$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Then for any $a \neq 0 \in \mathbb{C}$, the matrix $aM$ is nilpotent of order $n$, so it is similar to $M$. So there exists $L \in \mathcal{GL}_n({\mathbb{C}})$ such that $aM = LML^{-1}$, so $LM=aML$.

Answer (score 2):

We can do the $a = -1$ case in your title using [Clifford algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra). Namely, the Clifford algebra $\text{Cl}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ can be given a presentation with two generators $i, j$ subject to the relations

$$i^2 = j^2 = -1, ij + ji = 0.$$

This is exactly the algebra of [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) $\mathbb{H}$ and in particular is $4$-dimensional, with basis $\{ 1, i, j, ij \}$. The quaternions act on themselves by left multiplication and this gives a $4$-dimensional faithful representation of $\text{Cl}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ which is also its unique simple module. In this representation $i$ and $j$ act via the $4 \times 4$ matrices

$$L_i = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \end{array} \right]$$
$$L_j = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right].$$